# Directive unitTest controller returns empty object

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test an angular directive. I've done this before without any problem but today I got stuck. For sure is a silly error.

```
var element, scope, controller;


beforeEach(function() {
    angular.mock.module('templates');
    angular.mock.module('myApp.ui.apps.myMod');
    angular.mock.module('myApp.ui.apps.myMod.dropdown-parameter');

    angular.mock.inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache, $controller){
        scope = $rootScope;
        element = angular.element('<dropdown-parameter name-value-list="nameValueList" selected-option="selectedOption"></dropdown-parameter>');
        scope.nameValueList = [];
        var firstEnumValue =  {
                        "Name":"TestMock",
                        "Value":"TestMock1Value"
                     };
        var secondEnumValue = {
                            "Name":"TestMock",
                            "Value": "TestMock2Value"    
                     };

       scope.nameValueList.push(firstEnumValue);
       scope.nameValueList.push(secondEnumValue);
       scope.selectedOption={};
       $compile(element)(scope);
       scope.$digest();
       controller = $controller('dropdownParameterController' ,{$scope: scope});
      });
});

fit('Given an instantiated controller for dropdown parameter component when html is rendered then default value is the first one in the nameValueList', function(){
     console.log(controller); // HERE RETURNS {}
     expect(controller.selectedOption).toBe(controller.nameValueList[0].Value);
});
```

The problem is that controller is always equal to an empty object

console.log(controller) =====> {}
What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my controller && directive code.

```
var angular = require('angular');

module.exports = angular.module('myApp.ui.apps.myMod.dropdown-parameter', [])

.controller('dropdownParameterController', ['$scope', function($scope){
var self = this;
if(self.nameValueList)
{
    self.selectedOption = self.nameValueList[0].Value;
}
}])
.directive('dropdownParameter', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    bindToController: {
        nameValueList:'=',
        selectedOption:'='
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/ui/apps/diagnostics/dropdown-parameter/dropdown-parameter.html',
    controllerAs: 'dropdownParameterCtrl',
    controller: 'dropdownParameterController'
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

Angular detects when an injection is not used. In my case is the "$scope". After using it inside my controller everything started to work properly.

```
.controller('dropdownParameterController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    self.scope = $scope;

    if(self.nameValueList)
    {
        self.selectedOption = self.nameValueList[0].Value;
    }
}])
```